# How can I defer embedding a SWF until it's needed?

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex

I am developing a product that will be a combination of HTML5 and a Flash SWF (using the Flex framework) in a single page.  I'll put the SWF into a div that can be hidden/shown as needed.

The SWF will not be used all of the time, so I'd like to defer the embedding (or at least loading/starting) of it until the first time it's needed.  All the examples I've seen involve a static embedding, with the SWF is loaded/started when the page loads.

So how do I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, "I'll put the SWF into a div..."

Comment: Wouldn't you do this the same way you'd defer the loading of any HTML5ish content? Set the 'innerHTML' of a div?

Comment: How about creating this element (and inserting it into the DOM) when it's required?

Comment: You can embed / manipulate swf easily with SWF Object: https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Comment: Thanks, RafH.  I did it using SWFObject - very simple, exactly what I needed.